# Can anyone suggest good websites for self learning Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Am a beginner in Drupal.Can anyone suggest self learning websites for beginners with good examples?

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791035/good-beginners-material-advice-on-drupal

Answer (score 1):

some quickstart: http://www.scribd.com/doc/9740880/Quickstart-Guide-How-to-build-a-great-Drupal-website 
you can find everithing in drupal planet: http://drupal.org/planet

and my third favorite: http://www.learndrupalcms.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on what you define as "learning websites". 
You can roughly use Drupal for three things:

- Edit content in a site that someone built for you (Drupal enduser)
- Set up your own site, without programming (Drupal user)
- Develop your own modules, themes and such (Drupal as a development framework).

Once you have clear in what corner you want to start, I suggest looking at [Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com/ideas), a Drupal training company. Their free content is very scattered, and not very well organised, but it offers a lot of snippets of good information. Mostly development related.

For using and configuring Drupal, there are various screencasts at [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/handbook/customization/videocasts).

For end-user there is really no good general guide. That is, because Drupal can be (and will be) configured, specialised for you. No site has exactly the same administration as another site. Such manuals should be provided by the people building your site.